# How do i calculate sum and average number with decimals from a text file?

Tags: python, file, text, sum

```
50
17.32
32.99
51.02
15.61
23.94
5.99
12.1
62.74
105.59
16.50
32.99
23.71
54.90
19
17.52
48.6
102
99.99
73.05
```

this what i got so far.

```
file = open("saledata.txt", "r")
    line = file.readline()
    total = 0
    for line in open('saledata.txt'): total += float(line.strip())
```

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried to run your code? Also, did you try writing out the steps of the process you intend to follow, in plain English words, and then trying to write code for each step one at a time?

Answer (score 2):

Your `total` variable will already give you the sum. To get the average, you just need to divide by the total number of elements.

```
file = open("saledata.txt", "r")
line = file.readline() # I assume this is to ignore the first line
count = 0
total = 0
for line in open('saledata.txt'): 
    total += float(line.strip())
    count += 1
average = total/count
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a decimal counter variable to count every loop the for loop goes through (the numbers in the text file), then make a simple average variable and calculate :
average = total/count